# Cron jobs with whenever not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I'm trying to implement the gem "whenever" so that I can run automatic tasks every day.

This is my schedule.rb file:

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
set :output, "log/cron_log.log"

every :day, at: '10:10 am' do
  runner "Task.new.get_drivers"
end

every :day, at: '10:15 am' do
  runner "Task.new.get_deliveries"
end

every :day, at: '10:20 am' do
  runner "Task.new.update_deliveries"
end
```

In production, I ran this command line "whenever --update-crontab" as explained in the doc.

So far, everything seems to work fine. When I run the command line "whenever", I have this result:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/total/site/config/schedule.rb
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/total/.local/bin:/home/total/bin

10 10 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/total/site && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production '\''Task.new.get_drivers'\'' >> log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

15 10 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/total/site && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production '\''Task.new.get_deliveries'\'' >> log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

20 10 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/total/site && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production '\''Task.new.update_deliveries'\'' >> log/cron_log.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/total/site/config/schedule.rb
```

But finally, nothing happens (except when I run myself the cron jobs in my console). And my logs display nothing. Have you got any idea of what could be the problem ?

Thank you for your help.
Best regards,

Virginie

Comment: what is the output when you run it manually? (e.g. `cd /home/total/site && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production`)

Comment: My data are fetched and saved correctly in my db. But I have no logs about this process.

Comment: Can you try to schedule just something to log to try to debug the problem? I use `whenever` a lot without any issue for rake tasks. It might be that this is not executed for any of these reasons https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working

Comment: What I did is to run my tasks every three minutes and in this case, everything worked fine. My data were fetched and saved automatically in my db. But when I try to schedule my task at a specific time, it seems that nothing works. Maybe the problem comes from the time zone with which cron is running. How can I resolve it ?

Comment: If you are running every 3 minutes, the time zone is not relevant. I am thinking more about a permission issue due to the user which is running `bundle exec whenever --update-crontab`

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will inquire about this.

Answer (score 1):

Try `crontab -l` after deploy. This will open your crontab and list all tasks.
Then run `whenever --update-crontab` and check `crontab -l` again.
It could be that `whenever --update-crontab` didn't really update your crontab.

Also try to change `:day` to `1.day`

Also check if your Capfile contains `require 'whenever/capistrano'`, if you deploy via capistrano.